# build RS485 network on ROS

Tags: ros, hardware

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear All

I am testing the possibility of using ROS as a host to communicate with a 10 nodes RS485 network. Each node is one MCU with RS485 interface opened.

I looked through ros.org and ros answers did not get luck. Has any one done this type of work before? As a starting point, I am looking for a RoS compatible RS485 card and starting code to convert RS485 package to ros standard msg. Certainly you are more than welcome to send any suggestion on choosing other network such as CAN, Ethernet, or EtherCAT.  Thanks a lot.

Jayson

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11946/build-rs485-network-on-ros/) by [jayson ding](https://answers.ros.org/users/492/jayson-ding/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2011-11-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have a Ethercat master wrapped in ros [HERE](http://git.mech.kuleuven.be/robotics/soem.git). I think TUe wrote a driver for the beckhoff RS485 interface. It will also become available in SOEM.
Further more you can have a look at the FTDI interface modules. They just require a driver that opens the device node in linux.
It depends which type of functionality you wish of the RS485 interface. Personally I connect ROS to DMX (RS485 specific implementation for lighting) over a embedded controller.

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0